# push history in useEffect causes redirect in other routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, use-effect

I have this hook in my page:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (props.messages.msg !== "No token,authorization denied") {
      props.clearMsg();
      setInterval(() => {
        props.history.push("/");
      }, 2500);
    }
  }, [props.messages.msg, props.history]);
```

basically when I get a response from the server from redux, I redirect after 2.5 seconds to my root page,
and it works great, the problem is that when i'm at my root page and I try to go to a different route, I get redirected back to the root, as if the useEffect runs again, I tried to console log it and it doesn't seem to run again, so I have no idea why that happens, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you meant `setTimeout` here, which will only call the callback once:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.messages.msg !== "No token,authorization denied") {
      props.clearMsg();
      setTimeout(() => {
        props.history.push("/");
      }, 2500);
    }
  }, [props.messages.msg, props.history]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not the effect running more than once its that `setInterval` will run every 2.5 seconds. Use `clearInterval` when your component unmounts to prevent it from running again. Here is the docs on [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval).

Comment: Yeah I would say `setTimeout` is the better solution here.